# Create NotificationHub in script (Ruby preferred)

Tags: ruby, azure, azureservicebus, azure-notificationhub

We are building an automated testing service for our apps which use Notification Hubs for APNS messages. Part of this process would exercise push messages so we need an automated way to create Notification Hubs in some kind of script (I'm trying Ruby, but anything command-line oriented on OSX will work - I'll switch if needed)

I'm following this API guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223269.aspx (edit: corrected link) 
and SAS info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn170477.aspx

I'm trying to create a new Notification hub "testhub" under mybus.servicebus.windows.net "by hand" since none of the available SDKs seem to expose this particular function.

All my attempts are generating 401 errors - "InvalidSignature: The token has an invalid signature"

The SAS guide does not mention what the resource URI should be. I have tried the mybus.servicebus.windows.net as well as mybus.servicebus.windows.net/testhub and with or without http:// or https:// - the SAS info shows https: and a trailing "testhub". I even tried sb:// from the endpoint. However the API guide has an examples section where the SAS displayed does NOT include the hub name. No combo seemed to work for me.

I lifted this implementation from azure-push ruby code from github

```
require 'azure'

def MakeSASToken(url, key_name, access_key, lifetime)
  target_uri = CGI.escape(url.downcase).gsub('+', '%20').downcase
  expires = Time.now.to_i + lifetime
  to_sign = "#{target_uri}\n#{expires}"

  signature = CGI.escape( Base64.strict_encode64( Digest::HMAC.digest(to_sign, access_key, Digest::SHA256))).gsub('+', '%20')

  return "SharedAccessSignature sig=#{signature}&se=#{expires}&skn=#{key_name}sr=#{target_uri}"
end

DefaultAccessKey = 'RootManageSharedAccessKey'
Putrequest = 'mybus.servicebus.windows.net'
KeyValue='=Hsuperduperkeyvalue0='

puts "Creating request for #{Putrequest}"

tok = MakeSASToken("#{Putrequest}", DefaultAccessKey, KeyValue, 30)
puts tok`
```

Nothing seems to generate a valid token - what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Link you posted is about **Event Hub** which is not **Notification Hub**. Here is [Notification Hubs REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223269.aspx). Also you could use [.NET client library for ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/) or open source [Java SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-java-backend) which seems to be better option for your OS.

Comment: Thanks for that, efimovandr - corrected the link. Most of the rest of the iOS build automation tools seem to be in Ruby - but I might just fire up a Mono tool as you suggest :)